# Connection error in sending push notification

Tags: android, node.js, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app whose backend is a nodejs sails server. I have GCM push notification service installed on the server and I can send push notification to a user of my app using

```
curl http://localhost:1337/notification/1000
```

where for instance 1000 is the userID of the user to whom the notification is being sent.

Essentially, how it works is that this CLI will call a URL `/notification` with the userID of the user as URL parameter. The function defined on the `/notification` URL extracts the GCM registration id of this userID from the database, and sends a notification to this user on that registration ID, with the message content and type defined inside the function.

This method works perfectly well. But now I want to do this in bulk so as to send notification to all users. For this purpose, I have written a python script which is

```
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb.cursors import DictCursor
import os
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

#initiating the db
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'db_host', user = 'db_user_name', passwd = 'db_pass', db = 'db_schema_name')
queryCursor = db.cursor()

#finding users for whome recommendations are available
potentialUserDeterminationQuery = "select id from user"
queryCursor.execute(potentialUserDeterminationQuery)
availablePool = list(queryCursor.fetchall())
for elements in availablePool:
    userID = int(elements[0])
    os.system("curl http://localhost:1337/notification/" + str(userID))
queryCursor.close()
db.close()
```

**My issue:** When I send bulk notifications using this method, the notifications are sent to many users but also not sent to many users. I get the following server response when the notification could not be sent to a user:

```
connection refused on port 1337
```

**My workaround:**

(1) I came up with a possibility that the server might not be able to handle the notification request at this speed. So I introduced a delay of 20 ms after each notification is sent, using `time.sleep(0.02)` and had run the script again. But it again happened that few users didnt receive notification due to this error, while others got it.

(2) The problem could have been with userID if the DB had not stored the GCM registration ID properly and therefore server was unable to honor the request. So I tried sending individual push notification to that user through CLI and it worked. The user received notification when individually sent through CLI.

(3) This could be a periodic issue with the bulk notification script. Therefore I replaced userID inside the loop of the script, from `userID = int(elements[0])` to `userID = bugID` wher bugID is the userID of one of the users to whom notifications were not delivered during bulk messaging. So in essence I simulated the bulk message to all users on one single user. In this test too, all the messages got delivered to this user without any server connection refuse error.

**What can be a possible workaround apart from these three so that I can detect the issue and fix the system so that notification is then sent to everyone.**